# Receive an item from purchase order error

Tags: netsuite

I am having a trouble in NetSuite

- I create vendor, create product, make a purchase order, generate invoice, and pay for it all OK.

Then I go to purchase order and I click on receive to: then I add my storage click save and having this error:
Inventory revaluation is no longer the first transaction in your item history.

I need to make sale order after I have completed this.

Comment: If it was me I'd be having a look at the products that you are receiving/receipting in

Comment: I created only 1 product for test is that problem?

Comment: It looks to me like something wrong with the product setup. I have never really looked into netsuite much mind you, that's just my guess...

Comment: Can you please share the Product Details? This issue usually occurs due to Product been setup incorrectly.